# Question on dictionary software with some specific features allowed?

Tags: discusión, soporte

I'm looking for a dictionary software with some specific features, which I haven't found anywhere so far and would like to ask on this site if anyone knows of a program with those features. Will such a question be accepted? I don't want to elaborate on the features I'm looking for just to have the question closed immediately.

Comment: I'm also looking for a dictionary with a specific feature - specifically, a dictionary that makes it possible to search for words with a specific conjugation.

Comment: It would appear that there is general support for this type of question judging by the vote counts - 6 in favor and 0 against.  (But it's hard to be sure without seeing the question, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

I have my own [glossary of computer terminology](http://www.tugurium.com/gti) (> 22K terms). You can search for English terms to obtain translations, descriptions and links to other related terms either by similarity or by opposition. There are images included in some ones. It's just English to Spanish and free for everybody.

Comment: Hi there JL, could you mosey over to Resources for Learning?  I'm not sure the ping I sent you there will actually reach you.  Thanks.